# How can i call custom action on custom button click?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, controllers, overrides

I have created override file app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Block/Adminhtml/Import/Edit.php

and added a button

```
 $this->_addButton('downloadCsv', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Download CSV'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('/import/downloadcsv')}')",
        ));
```

in __construct()

it is work fine if add action function to core controller 
`app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php`

But i want to override controller. so i have created

`app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php`

and create

```
public function downloadcsvAction()
{
        // code 
}
```

but it is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi Sandeep,

Ideally, we should not override the controller with the same Namespace 'Mage'.
Just to check, have you followed all the steps for magento controller overriding. 
In your case : Namespace = 'Mage' 
Modulename = 'Importexport'

Please confirm the below things :

1.) in the config.xml of your app/code/local/mage/importexport/etc/config.xml, 
     <config>
       <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml</namespace_modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config> 

2.) In the file : 

app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php
Have you include the Core controller class like below : 


I hope my reply is helpful.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to override controller. 
Code in config.xml

```
 <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <custom_extension before="Mage_ImportExport">Custom_Extension_Adminhtml</custom_extension>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Code in your custom controller file

```
 require_once 'Mage'.DS.'ImportExport'.DS.'controllers'.DS. 'Adminhtml'.DS.'ImportController.php';
class Custom_Extension_Adminhtml_ImportController extends Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController
{//Your custom or overrided methods}
```